# WordPress .htaccess file blocking access to WHMCS Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, whmcs

I have a WordPress website that is using a WHMCS Bridge to integrate to WHMCS. It all works fine when the Permalinks are set to default. As soon as set them to Post Name - the .htaccess file changes and I can no longer access the WHMCS admin. The Client area and everything else works fine, but this throws a 404.

Does anyone have any ideas why?

WordPress is in `/public_html/`

WHMCS is in `/public_html/billing/`

WHMCS Admin is `/public_html/billing/admin`

.htaccess file has the default content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, I'm not an .htaccess guru.  Do you have a menu item in Wordpress with a permalink of 'billing'?  If so, I would imagine the permalink is mapping not to WHMCS but instead to that mapped menu item.  Then when going to /billing/admin it doesn't exist in Wordpress so it is throwing a 404.

So if /billing in Wordpress is a redirect to your /billing/clientarea.php file for example, that would work, but going to /billing/admin won't because Wordpress doesn't have a corresponding sub menu item called admin.

That's just a guess though... hope that is of help.